# Is the construction "as... also" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, construction

I came across the following sentence:

> "Every element of visual data can be viewed as in 3D also in 2D"

Is it correct to use here the construction "as...also..."?

Comment: _viewed in 3D or 2D_ would be more idiomatic. _as in_ has a meaning you don't want here and will confuse your readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not heard of it(i'm not native though). you could say ".... viewed as in both 3D and 2D.
by the way here is a link that I think could be helpful
https://www.englishforums.com/English/AsAlso/vrqgb/post.htm